# What is the purpose of the "user" global parameter in wp-cli.yml config?

Tags: wp-cli

According to [WP-CLI documentation](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/references/config/), you can specify "user" using inline arguments, or in the global configuration.

I understand there might be a task you want to run against a specific WordPress user, but what is the purpose of having a default WordPress user specificied in `wp-cli.yml` exactly? If anything, it seems a bit risky, or confusing.

Furthermore, why is `user: admin` recommended as a default value? That username hasn't been default in WordPress for several years already... are there security or usability concerns with defining this global option, esp. depending on various web hosting environments that may or may not include user-level `wp-cli.yml` files?

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between doing things to a user, and doing things as a user.

E.g. when you are logged in you are the current user, but by default in WP CLI there is no "current user". You can specify this via a parameter but adding a `user` via `wp-cli.yml` saves time. You may even create a dedicated alias for running commands as that user.

> Furthermore, why is user: admin recommended as a default value? That username hasn't been default in WordPress for several years already... are there security or usability concerns with defining this global option, esp. depending on various web hosting environments that may or may not include user-level wp-cli.yml files?

There's been a misunderstanding, `admin` is used as an example, not as a recommendation. The documentation is not telling you to use the value `admin` or suggesting its best practice. **Rather it's providing an example** so that people who want to use this option have an example they can compare against.

It's not telling you to use `admin`, it's saying if you wanted to use `user` with a value e.g. `admin`, that's what it would look like. You can see other uses of the `user` directive further down.

> are there security or usability concerns with defining this global option

If you have WP CLI access then it does not matter what the `user` parameter says, access has already been compromised, it's already game over. This is like asking if the shape of the buttons on your personal safe matter to burglars, after all WP CLI provides many other options, as well as `--user`.

> but what is the purpose of having a default WordPress user specificied in wp-cli.yml exactly? If anything, it seems a bit risky, or confusing.

Then don't specify a default user, most people do not do this, it requires additional steps. Most people don't have a config file in the first place when using WP CLI. It's simply an option that is available if it's convenient.